# Weird behaviour of MediaControllerCompat's onPlayFromMediaId() method

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer, mediabrowserservicecompat

I am working with a service which extends `MediaBrowserServiceCompat`, and also has `MediaSessionCompat.Callback()` with it's overridden methods inluding `onPlayFromMediaId()`.

Inside from a fragment which has recyclerview on click of the recyclerview item, following code is called. As from the image, it is clear that `mediaId` as well as `songBundle` have values and are being passed to the `onPlayFromMediaId()` method.

> [image]

The weird thing is, inside the Service class where the `playFromMediaId()` method is overriden, it only receives value for the string variable `mediaId` while the `songBundle` magically becomes empty. (Note- key used for putting and getting the parcelable is also same. The parcelable `songsVO` is a POJO which implements `Parcelable` interface.)

> [image]

Apart from this another interesting thing which I noticed is, when I return to the fragment which called the `onPlayFromMediaId()` later after it has been executed and check values of every variable, except `mediaId` every other variable becomes null.

> [image]
>   [image]

RecyclerAdapter class

```
  class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_song_item, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
//                    songPicked(position);
                songsVO=songsVOArrayList.get(position);
                mediaId=songsVO.getFilePath();
                songBundle=new Bundle();
                songBundle.putParcelable("song",songsVO);
//                    
  MediaControllerCompat.getMediaController(getActivity()).getTransportControls().playFromMediaId(mediaId, songBundle);


MediaControllerCompat.getMediaController(getActivity()).getTransportControls().play();
                currentState = STATE_PLAYING;

 holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(songsVOArrayList.get(position).getAlbumArt());
        holder.title.setText(songsVOArrayList.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.artist.setText(songsVOArrayList.get(position).getArtist());
        holder.duration.setText(songsVOArrayList.get(position).getDuration());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return songsVOArrayList.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CardView cardView;
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView title, artist, duration;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout_song_item);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_albumart);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
            artist = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_artist);
            duration = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_duration);
        }
    }
}
```

TLDR- `onPlayFromMediaId(String, Bundle)` passes only String variable while Bundle is passed empty.

Reference- [This tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/background-audio-in-android-with-mediasessioncompat--cms-27030)

Comment: Can you post your `RecyclerView` adapter class?

Comment: @azizbekian have added the adapter code as needed

Comment: Where is the `songBundle` declared?

Comment: Its a class variable, recycler adapter is an inner class to that class.

Comment: I am having a similar issue. Can you please share what the problem was? I posted a question about it with a bounty, you can answer there. Thanks!

Comment: Seeing the same problem on Android Automotive OS. In Android Auto it does work.